# Select option with a max value

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have a select with some option values

```
<select name="select">
   <option value="item-one">Item one</option>
   <option value="item-two">Item two</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="quantity">
```

If I selected Item one, I want the input number to have a max allowed value of 3, otherwise if Item two if selected it would be 4.

I tried looping it using foreach loop but wont return the right result

Comment: PHP is not the correct tool for this, you would normally implement such an interaction in Javascript.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to reproduce what you want to ask about.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in PHP but with JavaScript you can.

I use an array where the index matches the selectedIndex of the select

I trigger on load and I also reduce if the select is changed

I added an input event handler too, because min/max only works with the spinners AND the submit event.

Alternative for my input test is to set and trigger custom validity on the input field

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const sel = document.querySelector("[name=select]");
  const numberField = document.querySelector("[name=quantity]");
  sel.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    numberField.max = [3,4][e.target.selectedIndex];
    if (+numberField.value > +numberField.max) numberField.value = numberField.max;
  });
  sel.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // initial value
  numberField.addEventListener("input",(e) => {
    const val = numberField.value;
    if (+val > +numberField.max) numberField.value = numberField.max;
  })
  numberField.addEventListener("blur",(e) => {
    const val = numberField.value;
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(val)) || !isFinite(val)) numberField.value = 0; // field allows [e.-+] remove on blur if no digits
  })
});
```

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="item-one">Item one</option>
  <option value="item-two">Item two</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="quantity">
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. If I fill in 10 it doesn't work. Probably because JS sees it as a string.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `min` and `max` do not work that way. If you paste, they will be only be   validated on submit. You cannot use the spinner to more than max. Anyway I added code so it also tests when you type

Comment: Yes, now it is better. It still accepts non-numeric characters, and struggles with something like `-6`, but it is definitely good enough now.

Comment: Why is  -6 a problem? There was no requirement for a minimum.

Comment: I can only paste valid non-numeric characters like +-. into the field. I know -- and ++ are not valid numbers but that will be handled in the submit handler. I can add more validation on input if needed, but that was not in the requirements, but I added them now

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<option value="item-one">Item one</option>
   <option value="item-two">Item two</option>
</select>

<input id="quantity" type="number" name="quantity">

<script>
    document.getElementById('selectItem').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity');
        if (e.target.value === 'item-one') {
            quantityInput.max = 3;
        } else if (e.target.value === 'item-two') {
            quantityInput.max = 4;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That is not enough. See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76753204/295783)

Answer (score 0):

Php works on the server-side so you cant do that unless you send a command to the server. Its much easier to do in javascript.

Its not a good approach, but you can do something like this, to give you an idea, you can make an ajax request to the php side with javascript's onselect function. You will make a validator function on the php side and you will retrieve the data sent from onselect. After the validations, example you sent "Item One" , php validator will return you 3.
At the success method of javascript, you will take the returned data and set it to the input type as the max value with javascript again.

If there is complicated calculations that you want to make at the behind rather than this 3,4 this could be a way you are looking for. But if you just need 3,4 or simple things like that, just go with the javascipt.